# How to add a device to MobileFirst Operations Console?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How to add a device to MobileFirst Operations Console ?

I face issue in identifying my device in the MobileFirst Operations Console.

Please let me know how to configure my device to be detected in the console .

Comment: What do you mean? You do not add devices to the console. What are you attempting to do? Be clear in your explanation.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in my qs. I meant when I have installed the application to my real device, under the Devices tab of MobileFirst Operations Console , my device is not being detected.

Comment: @Gannu, what do you mean, "detected"? What are you expecting to see and where?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier My question was about why my MobileFirst Operations Console -> Devices (0) tab displays "Active Devices" as "0" even though I have connected my physical device (my mobile) to my computer and able to install my Androidapp from eclipse to my mobile. At the same time I am able to see the following tabs : Applications (1) and Adapters (4) where my application and all my adapters are displayed respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only feature related to "devices" is adding device simulation in the Console's Mobile Browser Simulator as described in the following user documentation topic: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/wl_studio_tools/topics/ttestwl.html?lang=en

The other feature related to devices is Device profiling, as described in the tutorial Getting Started tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/hello-world/introduction-to-mobilefirst-platform-operations-console/

Device profiling will be made possible after applications that are installed on simulators or devices are used and connect the MobileFirst Server. You can then create device profiling based on... devices.